# Are services intrinsically tied to hosts in Icinga?

Tags: monitoring, icinga

I am evaluating Icinga and Sensu for general service/host monitoring. One of the things we do with our services is manage them via orchestration tools (Mesos in our case). This prevents a service from necessarily running on any given host (it can run on any worker node).

Because we use service discovery, I can definitely write a monitoring plugin to execute my checks without having to know the host the service is executing a priori.

Icinga's service definitions seem to mandate that a service is tied to a host though. However, its host definitions don't require you to specify much of anything about the host. My question is this: Can I make a dummy host for a service or otherwise specify that a service isn't correlated with a particular host?

Answer (score 0):

Too late, but you of cause can create dummy host.
Use check_command check_dummy